# How to use EventSourceCreationData function?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Does anyone know what uses I need to add to access EventSourceCreationData?

Answer (score 1):

The [`EventSourceCreationData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventsourcecreationdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a Net class, if you want write to the Windows log using Delphi you must try the WinAPI [`Event Logging Functions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363654(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Hi RRUZ, I add more information about my question. I'm using WinAPI but it's not working as I expected

Comment: You can't change the original question on the fly, instead you must rollback your edit and then ask a new question providing a sample code and following these guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I can not rollback. Unfortunately only has two revisions and neither is my original question. I will create a new question. Thank you

Comment: I just rollback to the original question.